# UWP Open New Window in Class

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core, new-window, openpages

There are too many pages in my project and I want to write the opening and closing of these pages in one class. But it does not open to a new page.

Thank you.

My Class Code

```
class Class
{
    public static void GoToOpenPage1()
    {
        Frame OpenPage1 = new Frame();
        OpenPage1.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

Button Click Code

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class.GoToOpenPage1();
    }
```

Comment: May i know the app is running on Windows IoT Core?If yes, Windows IoT Core only support single-page UWP app, it can not open a new page like on Windows desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create a `Frame`, it needs to be inserted into the current visual tree so that it can be "see".

For example, we create a Grid in `MainPage.xaml`.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="FrameContainer"  x:FieldModifier="public">

</Grid>
```

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`, we can expose the MainPage instance through static variables.

```cs
public static MainPage Current;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Current = this;
}
```

In this way, when `MainPage` is loaded, `FrameContainer` will also be loaded. We can get this `Grid` externally through `MainPage.Current.FrameContainer`, and then insert the `Frame` we generated into this `Grid`, which completes the insertion into the visual tree step.

```cs
public static void GoToOpenPage1()
{
    Frame OpenPage1 = new Frame();
    OpenPage1.Navigate(typeof(OtherPage));
    MainPage.Current.FrameContainer.Children.Clear();
    MainPage.Current.FrameContainer.Children.Add(OpenPage1);
}
```

But judging from the code you provided, you seem to be navigating to `MainPage`. If you need to make `MainPage` become the content of the Window again, you can write like this:

```cs
var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

---

The above content belongs to page navigation, if you want to open a new window, you can refer to this document, which provides detailed instructions:

- [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views)

Answer (score 1):

If you target Windows 10 version 1903 (SDK 18362) or later, you could open a window using the `AppWindow` API:

```
class Class
{
    public static async Task GoToOpenPage1()
    {
        AppWindow appWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
        Frame OpenPage1 = new Frame();
        OpenPage1.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindow, OpenPage1);
        await appWindow.TryShowAsync();
    }
}
```

On earlier versions, you should create a `CoreApplicationView`:

```
class Class
{
    public static async Task GoToOpenPage1()
    {
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame OpenPage1 = new Frame();
            OpenPage1.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            Window.Current.Content = OpenPage1;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
    }
}
```